# Openresty Docker container when try RUN, return nginx: invalid option: "/bin/sh"

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, lua, openresty

I try build an imagen with openresty:centos and the imagen is Successfully built, but when try tu RUN a container with this image the container STOP ans show this message:

nginx: invalid option: "/bin/sh"

```
FROM openresty/openresty:1.11.2.3-centos

RUN yum install openssl-devel -y

RUN /usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin/luarocks install lua-cjson
RUN /usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin/luarocks install lua-resty-jwt
RUN /usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin/luarocks install lua-resty-redis
RUN /usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin/luarocks install luacrypto
RUN /usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin/luarocks install lualogging
RUN /usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin/luarocks install luaposix
RUN /usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin/luarocks install uuid

RUN PATH=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin:$PATH
RUN export PATH

COPY ./src/api-gw/conf/nginx.conf /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf

COPY ./src/api-gw/lib/authentication.lua /usr/local/openresty/lualib
COPY ./src/api-gw/lib/logger.lua /usr/local/openresty/lualib
COPY ./src/api-gw/lib/redis.lua /usr/local/openresty/lualib
COPY ./src/api-gw/lib/uses_cases.lua /usr/local/openresty/lualib
COPY ./src/api-gw/lib/utils.lua /usr/local/openresty/lualib

RUN mkdir /home/app

COPY ./src/api-gw/api-gw.lua /home/app

EXPOSE 80

CMD nginx -p /usr/local/openresty/nginx -c nginx.conf
```

command for build image:

```
docker build -t openresty_test .
```

command for RUN a container:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:80 --name img_resty openresty_test
```

response:

```
nginx: invalid option: "/bin/sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Dockerfile](https://github.com/openresty/docker-openresty/blob/1.11.2.3/centos/Dockerfile#L103), you should override `ENTRYPOINT` rather than `CMD`. See [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) for details.

`ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are combined, so you are actually trying to execute:

```
$ /usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -g 'daemon off;' /bin/sh -c 'nginx -p /usr/local/openresty/nginx -c nginx.conf'
nginx: invalid option: "/bin/sh"
```

I would also recommend you to use *exec form* of `CMD`/`ENTRYPOINT` (`["executable","param1","param2"]`, not `executable param1 param2`)